# Optimal strategy puzzle

Tags: probability, optimization

Play a game with an urn. $75$ blue balls. $25$ red balls. $1$ yellow ball. you get a dollar for every red and if you select the yellow you lose everything. what should be your strategy in the game. you can choose to stop or re-draw after every ball.

Comment: Do you put a ball back in the urn after selecting it, or are there less and less balls in the urn the more you play?

Comment: @ferson2020: I assume you can't put the ball back. What's the fun if done so?

Comment: Ok, so say I play, and I win a dollar because I drew a red ball. I put the red ball back in, and play again (if I want to play again), right? I don't keep the red ball out and have a greater chance of losing the second time, do I? Just want to make sure I understand the rules correctly.

Comment: @ferson2020: Every time you put the ball back in, you have an equal chance of winning every time. Do you wanna play a game where losing is just $0.99 % $ probable? . I'm **not** sure of the rules.

Comment: @Inceptio:  it is a reasonable question either way.  The answer will be different, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I assume the player is risk neutral.

After each draw the player makes a decision about whether to continue. Let R,B be the number of red and blue balls that have been drawn before. The player should continue to draw so long as the expected value of drawing is greater than 0.

$0\left(\frac{75-B}{\left(75-B\right)+\left(25-R\right)+1}\right)+1\left(\frac{25-R}{\left(75-B\right)+\left(25-R\right)+1}\right)-R\left(\frac{1}{\left(75-B\right)+\left(25-R\right)+1}\right)>0$

Thus, the player will draw so long as probability of gaining $1 (drawing a red ball) is greater than the loss of drawing a yellow ball (R) multiplied by the probability of drawing a yellow ball.

Player solves:

$\frac{25-R}{\left(75-B\right)+\left(25-R\right)+1}>\frac{1}{\left(75-B\right)+\left(25-R\right)+1}R$

$\frac{25}{2}>R$

The player should continue to draw until 13 red balls have been drawn.

Comment: You can save a little work by pretending the blue balls aren't there as they don't affect anything.

Comment: I agree. The expressions would be interpreted with conditional probabilities in that case. Expected values conditional on not having drawn a blue ball.